# UIView animation that mimics presentViewController easing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a view which animates from the bottom of my ViewController, and I'm trying to get the animation to be the same as the default

```
present(viewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

I want to animate a view with the same easing and timing as the above code. Right now I'm using this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.myView.frame = newFrame
}, completion: nil)
```

The animations aren't similar though, and I don't know what values to use in my UIView animation to make it look like a viewController present. Anyone know what values could get me close?

Answer (score -1):

here is sample code with somewhat animation like presenting viewcontroller

```
var subViewNew = UIView()
```

make initial dream setup of you subview which you want to make to add on main view as below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        subViewNew.frame = CGRect(x: 100,y: 100,width:self.view.frame.width - 200,height:200)
        self.subViewNew.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height
        subViewNew.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }
```

for appearance of the view subview you can go like this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            self.subViewNew.frame.origin.y = 300 + 20
            self.view.addSubview(self.subViewNew)
        })
```

for dismiss or hiding it you can go like this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            self.subViewNew.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height
            self.subViewNew.removeFromSuperview() //If you want then only
        })
```

Hope this help you

Comment: This animation is much slower than the default view controller present animation, and it's linear. I'm looking for one with the same timing and easing as you see in present(viewController, animated)

Comment: @LulzCow you can achieve it by duration you want

Comment: yes, but my question was about exact timing and easing, or other animation options to make it appear exactly like the default viewController present animation.